# Stability of Peroxynitric Acid in cold temperature

Tags: stability, molecules, temperature

I have a question about the stability of Peroxynitric Acid i.e. $\ce{HO2NO2}$
at cold temperature. I know that it becomes stable when temperature decreases, but what is the specific reason for it? I guess it has to do with the temperature changing the potential hypersurface, but I'm not sure. I also seem to not be able to find a good explanation about it in the internet, since most is about the kinetics I'm not interested in. Possibly, this question relates to all PAN-like species i.e. $\ce{R(O)OONO2}$ such as the acetylperoxy nitrate. Any good physical explanation? Thanks

Comment: High entropy of decomposition, I guess.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?